# Pass ICommand Action through MVXValueConverter in MVVVMCross with Binding in iOS-Android

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am creating a Cross Platform application in Xamarin MVVMCross in which I am using an Attributed Text for showing a clickable link on some part of a text.

I have created my custom class with **MvxValueConverter** and applied a Binding in my iOS class.

Below is my code.

```
public class FreeShippingConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, NSAttributedString>
    {
        protected override NSAttributedString Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var result = new NSMutableAttributedString(value);
            var startIndex = value.IndexOf(Strings.Test, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (startIndex < 0)
            {
                return result;
            }

            var range = new NSRange(startIndex, Strings.Test.Length);
            result.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.Font, TextStyle.B2Bold.Font(), range);
            result.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, Colors.Bluescale4.ToNativeColor(), range);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Below is the Binding code from TableViewCell.

```
this.CreateBinding(FreeShippingText).For(v => v.AttributedText).To((FulfilmentOptionsCellViewModel vm) => vm.FreeShippingText).WithConversion<FreeShippingConverter>().Apply();
```

[image: Output]

Now I want to create an Action when user clicks on "**Perks Members**".

How to bind that in iOS and Android?

Please help me.

Comment: ValueConverters are not intended to do bindings for your. Instead, you may need to create your own Binding Target to handle this instead, which formats the text in the desired format and accepts a ICommand for the action. If you insist on doing i through the ValueConverter, you could pass the Command through the converter Parameter.

Comment: Can you please explain via an example? That would be a great help.

Comment: Can you explain how to bind vakue converter through Icommand in ios-Android?

Comment: Which arguments does `WithConversion<T>` take? Explore that and you will have your answer.

Comment: @Cheesebaron: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376656/set-icommand-through-mvxvalueconverter-in-xamarin-ios-android-using-mvvmcross

Comment: It takes ICommand but I don't know how to use that for multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Can this achieve your need?

Create a VM class:

```cs
namespace Forms1.ViewModels
{
    public class VM
    {
        public ICommand SomeActionsCommand { get; set; }
        void SomeActions()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("some actions");
        }
        public VM()
        {
            SomeActionsCommand = new Command(SomeActions);
        }
    }
}
```

In your MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Forms1.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Forms1.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:VM/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


   <StackLayout Padding="10,10">
        <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="FREE Shipping For " TextColor="#465978" />
                    <Span Text="Perks Members" TextColor="#2d3f62" FontAttributes="Bold"  FontSize="Large">
                        <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SomeActionsCommand}" />
                        </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Span>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage>
```

And here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/SFasein).

Comment: I am developing in MVVMCross so I have separate files for iOS and Android UI and Viewmodels for shared.

Comment: Any idea in Xamarin MVVM Cross?